# Check if the link exists

Tags: javascript

On the web page I'm working on, clicking on the link occurs due to the function `sendEvent('openassignment','mx145','0')`, the link number is passed in the third parameter of this function, 0 is the first link, 1 is the second link, 2 is the third link, etc. I need to programmatically check if the link exists. For example, there is no link number 30 on the page, how do I check it?

I need to implement: if I followed the link, then we output "everything is ok" if the link is missing, then there will be no transition, and then how to catch this moment?

```js
const myTask = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(sendEvent('openassignment', 'mx145', '0'));
});

async function myt() {
    await myTask().then(() => {
        // if I followed the link, then we output "everything is ok"
        // if the link is missing, then there will be no transition, and then how to catch this moment?
    });
}

myt();
```

Comment: make a fetch call or a head request with xmlhttprequest

Comment: With the number of link, do you mean the, for example, 30th link on the page? Or does the link itself have an actual number?

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier, Yes, i mean 30th link on the page

Comment: @Shahkumar41 did you get a chance to take a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First select the `nth-of-type` link by using [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). This allows us to target a specific link and see if it exists **and** has a `href` property.

Then make a `fetch` request with the `href` value and see if you get a successful response. If `response.ok` is true, then the link exists.

```
async function checkNthOfLink(numberOfLink) {
  const link = document.querySelector(`a:nth-of-type(${numberOfLink})`);
  if (link === null || !link.href) {
    return false;
  }

  const { ok } = await fetch(link.href, {
    method: 'HEAD'
  });

  return ok;
}
```

You can use it like here below. The `result` value will either be `true` or `false`. Based on that you can call your `sendEvent` function.

```
checkNumberOfLink(30).then(result => {
  if (result === true) {
    sendEvent('openassignment', 'mx145', '30')
  }
});
```